# FTP IIS rename received files

Tags: iis, ftp

We have got some machines sending files via FTP to our server. Sadly in some cases the generated files can have the same name and will be overwritten on the server before they're processed there.

The FTP sender system we are not able to change anything (closed system).

Is there a possibilty to change the file name (maybe to some random one, a guid oder something) after IIS FTP server processed the upload but before the file is written to the disk?

e.g.

Source -> Destination

```
file1.txt -> 235987298735236.txt
file2.txt -> 468934693469464.txt
```

and so on...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can still try to write a windows service which will watch the specified folder, and when a new file arrives it can rewrite the name of the file, however its not completely fool proof as if two machines send the same file at the same time it might be an issue.

in such case i would request to look into the IIS APIs for FTP and see if there is any event triggers when incoming file.